# Can skill ranks be spent at level 1?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills

Can a character put skill ranks into skills at level 1? I am brand new to ***Pathfinder*** and don't know if that's allowed. All the information I get is from [*Masterwork Tools*](http://www.legolas.org/masterwork-tools/), which was very vague on the subject.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour]. I've taken the liberty of editing your question's tags and the question itself; if I've made an error, feel free to correct it. Thank you for participating, and enjoy your new experience with *Pathfinder*.

Answer (score 8):

Chargen software is useful but is no substitute for learning the rules for creating a character. To learn the rules of creating a character you should read the “Generating a Character” section of the [*Pathfinder Roleplaying Game Core Rulebook*](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/47927/pathfinder-roleplaying-game-core-rulebook) (p. 14), or the [Character Creation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/character-creation) section of the [online System Reference Document](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/) (SRD).

For skills, the answer is found in Step 4 (in the book; oddly it's Step 5 in the SRD), which instructs you to (and how to) allocate your skill ranks at 1st level.

Comment: Masterwork Tools is an app that contains everything available from the Pathfinder Open Reference SRD.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes.

Skill ranks are awarded at level 1, using the listed value under your class entry.  You can only assign one rank in a skill per level, so at first level any given skill can only have 1 one rank.

In addition, class skills (listed under the class entry in MWK Tools) gain a class bonus of +3 as long as you have spent at least one rank in the skill.